# Line Chart labels is overlapping - Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using a Line Chart with two series (Month, Value, Goal) with annotations, but the labels are overlapping. I tried using stem, font-size, change scale, targetAxisIndex, etc.

Is there a way to fix this?

[Chart overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlOvl.jpg)

How can I solve it? This code was my last attempt.

```
series: {
            1: {
                type: 'line',
                pointSize: 5,
                annotations: {
                    stem: {
                        length: 0
                    }
                },
                targetAxisIndex:1 

            },
            2: {
                annotations: {
                    stem: {
                        lenght:17
                    },
                    targetAxisIndex: 2                       
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I have this column. As I am not configuring my 0 serie (month), I think it's not necessary, right? Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: in the series option, `0` refers to the first column after the x-axis column -- series 0 = column 1